# How to expand and collapse the height of a particularly selected div?

Tags: angular, ionic2

**Requirement--**  I want to expand and collapse the height of particularly selected `div`.

**Current position--**  Below is my html code. I used `*ngfor` to display data and there is a `div` to describe the data `list.TASKDESC`. I used click method to increase and decrease the height of `div`. It increases and decreases each `div`  height at the same time.

```
<ion-list no-lines *ngFor="let list of displayList;let i=index;" >

    <ion-item text-wrap *ngIf="list.STATUS=='ACTIVE'" style="padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;">

      <div (click)="isExpanded = !isExpanded" [style.height]="isExpanded?'auto':'20px'">
        <p style="color: #9DA4AB;font-size: 15px;">{{list.TASKDESC}}</p>
        <hr>
        <p style="color: #9DA4AB;font-size: 10px;">{{list.DEADLINE_DT}}</p>
      </div>
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**Before click**

[image]

**After click**

[image]

Comment: < div (click)="list.isExpanded = !list.isExpanded" [style.height]="list.isExpanded?'auto':'20px'" > That's "isExpanded" must be a variable of each item

Comment: thanks....it works..